# Can a ML USB stick created with Lion Diskmaker be shared with others (who have their own ML license)?

Tags: macos, license, usb

I purchased and downloaded Mountain Lion from the App Store for my own personal use. I created a bootable USB stick using the [Lion Diskmaker](http://blog.gete.net/lion-diskmaker-us/) utility to make it easier to install and for any future reinstalls.

My boss has also purchased a copy of Mountain Lion from the App Store for her own Macs, but the download is taking forever.

Is there any difference between the USB stick created using my ML download, versus a USB stick created using someone else's ML download? Is it okay to use my USB stick in lieu of someone else's download to upgrade other Macs for people (assuming they already have a license for Mountain Lion)?

**Update:** I ran a `diff --recursive` on the two downloads, and the only difference between them was `Install OS X Mountain Lion.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt`. So technically they *are* slightly different, but functionally they're identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, there are no technical differences. And, yes, its ok to use someone else's Mountain Lion image, if you've purchased your own copy.